# EF6 WCF Data Service Exposes Singular Entity Type Names Instead of the Pluralized DbSet Property Names

Tags: entity-framework, odata, entity-framework-6, wcf-data-services

I'm new to EF. I've created an ODataV3 WCF Data Service in an ASP.NET web app. My DataContext class has my entity sets defined as properties of type DbSet where TEntity are my entity POCOs. The names of the properties are plural and my entity classes are singular.

Now the weird part. When I try to access an entity set using a url like http://myservice/ApplicationData.svc/Widgets, I get the following back:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code />

<m:message xml:lang="en-US">Resource not found for the segment 'Widgets'.</m:message>

</m:error>
```

Indeed, when I go to ApplicationData.svc, I see all my collections listed in singular form.

My DataContext class definitely has no DbSet properties with singular names - they are all pluralized. Here's a snippet of it:

```
/// <summary>Gets an object query for the entity set 'Accreditation', containing entity type 'Accreditation'</summary>
public DbSet<Accreditation> Accreditations { get; set; } 
/// <summary>Gets an object query for the entity set 'AdditionalChargeTaxType', containing entity type 'AdditionalChargeTaxType'</summary>
public DbSet<AdditionalChargeTaxType> AdditionalChargeTaxTypes { get; set; } 
/// <summary>Gets an object query for the entity set 'AdditionalChargeTaxTypeStateProvince', containing entity type 'AdditionalChargeTaxTypeStateProvince'</summary>
public DbSet<AdditionalChargeTaxTypeStateProvince> AdditionalChargeTaxTypeStateProvinces { get; set; } 
/// <summary>Gets an object query for the entity set 'AdditionalChargeType', containing entity type 'AdditionalChargeType'</summary>
public DbSet<AdditionalChargeType> AdditionalChargeTypes { get; set; }
```

I want the service to expose the plural names I used for the properties - Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider seems to be using the singular *element type names* instead.

I tried falling back to EF5 (which uses a service derived from DataService instead of EF6 provider's need for EntityFrameworkDataService). But I got the same singular instead of plural behaviour.

I tried unit testing the generated DataContext directly and it works as expected:

```
var query = (from w in context.Widgets select w); // Works with the plural "Widgets" as expected
```

How can I make my OData service use my data context's plural property *names* instead of exposing singular entity set names it is getting from I-don't-now-where?

Comment: what does the output of `ApplicatoinData.svc` show?

Comment: @Claies: Singulars of all my entity sets. I've updated my question to say so.

Comment: How is your `ApplicationData` class declared? is it `ApplicationData : EntityFrameworkDataService<DbContext>` or is it `ApplicationData : DataService<DbContext>`? or some other variation?

Comment: @Claies: I've tried both (EntityFrameworkDataService<> when linked to EF6 and Microsoft.Data.* and DataService<> when linked to EF5) and both produced the same singular-instead-of-plural result.

Comment: do you have any customizations at all in the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`?

Comment: @Calies: ODataConvetionModelBuilder? Can't even find that literal when I search my solution. But you've got me thinking - my EDMX is generated by LLBLGen - not VS. I didn't think that was relevant since the resulting generated entity classes and datacontext classes are all that matter, no?

Comment: Just like Entity Framework, OData has a convention builder where you can override conventions, and even give custom names to the entity sets. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.builder.odataconventionmodelbuilder(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: does LLBLGen use the `RemovePluralizations` convention (i.e. are your table names singular in SQL)?

Comment: @Calies: (tried to move to chat but "failed"). Thanks - I opened the EDMX and noted that the EntitySet elements in the ConceptualModel all had singular Name attributes. I changed one to plural and rebuilt and - voila! - entity set is now exposed in plural form. But now I am completely confused as to the purpose of the DbSet<TEntity> properties generated in the DataContext! What's the point of them? Isn't EDMX a design-time file so how can it be affecting the reflection at runtime? My DB entities are singular but I don't know about any EF Conventions by LLBLGen.

Comment: I don't really know all the ins and outs of LLBLGen, but I suspect that it has some convention that is similar to the Entity Framework `RemovePluralizations`, allowing you to have Plural `DbSet<T>` even with singular database tables.  My guess is that OData is somehow picking up this convention, and generating your OData models to match the Db, not the `DbSet<T>`

Comment: changing those attributes in the EDMX won't have an affect on your `DbSet<T>` unless you regenerate your models.

Comment: @Calies: I'm still confused about why WCF is exposing collections in the singular form when all this time my generated DataContext class has had plural names for the DbSet<TEntity> properties. All I want is for the service to expose my entity sets with a URL path that matches the DataContext property names. Thanks for your help anyways.